# unable to install laravel homestead using command line

Tags: laravel-5

i am trying to install laravel homestead in my windows 7 pc but every time fails it starts downloading but after some percentage it stops and display errors like

> "SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054"

i have restarted download but every time after some percentage it stops i am tired now please help me

i have installed **"vagrant_1.7.4.msi"** and **"VirtualBox-4.3.30-101610-Win.exe"** also

Comment: Download the .box file and add like this `vagrant box add laravel/homestead file:///c:/homestead-0-2-6-vb.box`, this is the only way I could install it in Windows 7.

Comment: where to download the .box file can give me the link?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also unable to install it online in Windows 7, it will always stop downloading at some point before 15%.

What I had to do was to download the `.box` file and add it locally.

You can download the file from:

`https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.7/providers/virtualbox.box`

For convenience rename it to something like `homestead-0-2-7-vb.box` and do the following:

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead file:///c:/homestead-0-2-7-vb.box`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
vagrant box add --insecure -c laravel/homestead http://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
```

It worked for me.
Got it from [here](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/401)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't finish even the manual download, try to download from this [mirror](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxiUDyf4p8pdZHpPUGhwVkJ2VWc/view?usp=sharing). This is a copy of laravel/homestead 0.5.0. Use this command to add:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead "path-to-your-file"
```

Comment: Thank you!  That mirror helped me a year later (because the same problems exist a year later).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error "errno 10054".
However, in my environment I solved it with the following contents.

- Windows10 64bit
- Git bash 2.21.0
- Virtual Box 6.0.4
- vagrant 2.2.4

As a result, this was necessary for me.
MSVCR100.DLL
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632

In my case, the installation was successful if I do it as follows.

1. To install "MSVCR100.DLL" on windows
2. To command "Vagrant box add laravel/homestead" at terminal.